# ajax serialize post null value c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

im trying to pass a value to a controller using ajax post. i already tried some of the answered question here in this community but still no luck.

Javascript:

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datastring = $("#createtrform").serialize();
        console.log(datastring); // printed from console./ travelerID=123123123&name0=&mail0=&mobile0
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url: pageBaseURL + "Transactions/Save",
            data: JSON.stringify(datastring),
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }               
        });           
        return false;
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string data = null)
{
 Debug.WriteLine(data);
 object var = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data); //error here that says 'System.ArgumentNullException'

 return Context(data.traverID);
}
```

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: what happens when you do this `data: { data: JSON.Stringify(datastring) }`

Comment: @Ric thanks for the response. but its still the same.

Comment: what does the "JSON.stringify(datastring)" returns? would you mind printing it in console.log as well? also, you may remove the "= null" from your method, "string data" should do the job.

Comment: hi @kenlacoste i still having this issue for about 2days now. lol the result of the "JSON.stringify(datastring)" is something like this "travelerID=123123&name0=&mail0=&mobile=". i also tried removing the `=null` in the method but still  in the server gives me a null value. im open for any suggestion. since im still not getting the hang of it.

Comment: thats alright :). That result is definitely not a JSON result, the result must be something like [ {"travelerID":"123123"},{"name0":""},{"mail0",""},{"mobile":""} ] if stringfied correctly. try doing this. data : {data:datastring},

Comment: @kenlacoste i tried using the `data=JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());`  which give result a `[{"name":"traverID","value":"12341"},...]` . tried doing the `data: {data: data}` and it successfully pass the `jsonObject` to the server. thanks!